# Retrieving NULL values from S3 while Select query AWS Redshift spectrum

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I am able to unload data to S3, and query the results with Spectrum, but NOT when using the delimiter defined below. This is our standard delimiter that works with all of our processing today related to Redshift COPY and UNLOAD commands, so I believe the UNLOAD is working fine. But somewhere between the table definition and the SQL query to retrieve the data, this is not working. We just receive NULLS for all of the fields. Can you look at our example below in order to determine next steps.

```
unload ('select * from db.test')
to 's3://awsbucketname/ap_cards/'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::123456789101:role/redshiftaccess'
delimiter '\325'
manifest;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE db_spectrum.test (
cost_center varchar(100) ,
fleet_service_flag varchar(1)
)
row format delimited
fields terminated by '\325'
stored as textfile
location 's3://awsbucketname/test/';

select * from db_spectrum.test
```

Comment: I'm curious what happens when you use another delimiter (one of the standard ASCII octal codes)? Do you still get NULL?

Comment: Hi Khalid T. , the delimiter works while creating the table but I guess there is a problem in external tables interpreting delimiters. I am stuck here :(

Comment: did you try to create external table with another delimiter for example '|'. how did you test that the unload works fine?

Comment: Yes, the command works with '|', but the problem is it does work with '\325' when I unload from redshift to S3 gzip and then create the external table. But the surprising thing is the file gets loaded with '\199' in S3. But all my files are already lying on S3 with '\325' gzip format. And when I select the data, I recieve null values.

Comment: And the problem lies in my mapping from S3. It retrieved results from S3 when unload and create external table was done using 'Õ' but not using its octal equivalent '\325'. Could you please help me with this as all my tables are already unloaded with '\325'.

Answer (score 1):

Got a response from AWS Support center as:
Unfortunately you will need to either process the data externally to change the delimiter or UNLOAD the data again with a different delimiter.

The docs say to [Specify a single ASCII character for 'delimiter'](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE.html).

The ASCII range only goes up to 177 in octal.

We will clarify the docs to note that 177 is the max permissible octal for a delimiter. I can confirm that this is the same in Athena as well.

Thank you for bringing this to our attention.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using [Spectrify](https://github.com/hellonarrativ/spectrify/) for this.  It automates a lot of the nastiness involved currently with moving redshift table to spectrum.

Comment: Thanks for this! Will try it.